# Deploying to website with Git remotes, but without post-receive hook

Tags: git

I want to deploy my website using git, but I have a severe problem: my hosting provider doesn't allow git hooks to run. How can I deploy my site without it? I can even manually run some scripts.

Comment: Have you absolutely settled on git as the deployment tool?  You may have better luck with something designed with deployment in mind, such as [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano)

Comment: @gcbenison I'm sure I want git. Git is out-of-the-box on majority of setups. Plus, I want Git. Not Capistrano or other.

Comment: Got it.  I'll just mention though, that to deploy to a set of servers with Capistrano, you don't need to install Capistrano on those servers.  You just need to be able to ssh to them.

Answer (score 5):

Run manually the same steps that you would normally do in your post-receive hook, most importantly:

```
cd /path/to/website
git pull
```

This assumes that `/path/to/website` is a clone from your Git repository, and you have configured its current branch to track the branch of the Git repository where you deploy your releases.

So after you push your commits to your Git repository, you can bring your website up to date with:

```
ssh yourserver 'cd /path/to/website; git pull'
```

Comment: ...and that's basically what Capistrano does, with some bells and whistles added like keeping the previous release around so you can roll back to it quickly